# JavaScript form error state does not stay on same page

Tags: javascript, popup, alert

I'm doing a simple validation for a form. The JavaScript validation works fine and the pop up alert box appears with the correct errors, BUT, upon clicking "Ok", I get re-directed to the next page. Ideally, it is supposed to stay at the same page so that the user can amend his/her mistakes.

This is a school project.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function show_alert() {
    if (document.getElementById('time1').value == document.getElementById('time2').value) alert("ERROR! You cannot book the same timing twice!")
    else if (document.getElementById('time1').value == document.getElementById('time3').value) alert("ERROR! You cannot book the same timing twice!")
    else if (document.getElementById('time1').value == document.getElementById('time4').value) alert("ERROR! You cannot book the same timing twice!")
    else if (document.getElementById('time1').value == "0") alert("ERROR! You cannot leave the first time slot blank!")
    else {}
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be easy to fix.  In the onsubmit method of your form tag, do this:

```
<form onsumbit="return show_alert();">
```

Instead of

```
 <form onsumbit="show_alert();">
```

Without the `return` part, the script will run, and the form will be submitted anyhow.  Also, if there is an error condition in the script, you need to add a `return false;` otherwise the form will still be submitted, and `return true;` if there is no error.  You can edit the script like so:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function show_alert() {
    if (document.getElementById('time1').value == document.getElementById('time2').value) {
        alert("ERROR! You cannot book the same timing twice!");
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('time1').value == document.getElementById('time3').value) {
        alert("ERROR! You cannot book the same timing twice!");
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('time1').value == document.getElementById('time4').value) {
        alert("ERROR! You cannot book the same timing twice!");
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('time1').value == "0") {
        alert("ERROR! You cannot leave the first time slot blank!");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Also, `show_alert` needs to return true or false indicating whether the form should be submitted or not.

Comment: @casablanca Yeah - I was adding that as you left the comment...got distracted while answering, and left it out accidentally.  :-)

Comment: @jeremy I just tried that, but it doesn't stay on the same page. It still goes to the next page. This is the codes for the button: <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="show_alert()"/> and this is the code for the form:<form action="booking_now.php" method="POST" id="form1" onSubmit="return show_alert();">

Comment: Can you please please give me an example. Perhaps I can email you the files? It will be very much appreciated :D

Comment: @Chandni You do not need the `onclick="show_alert()"` on the submit button if you put it in the `onsubmit` portion of the `<form>` tag.  Also, check my updated answer for the script modifications that are needed.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, but I have another question. I have a hardcoded javascript calendar and I need to print the events from my database which is a PHP MySQL server side database. But I'm not sure how to fetch the queries from mysql and print it into the javascript calendar :/ I found something that makes use of VBSCRIPT but its very confusing :/

Comment: That is a complicated issue.  Attempting to query MySQL directly in your javascript is not advisable.  It would be better to do it in a PHP script, or another server-side scripting language if PHP is not available.  It might be better to ask a new question for that, though here is some documentation for querying MySQL in PHP: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php